# console не видит проект

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

При запуске `rails console` не видит проект.
Пробовал пересоздать gemset. Использую **Ruby 2.0.0** со своим gemset'ом.
Что может быть не так? Почему не видит приложение?
Сайт с приложением работает, все отлично.

```
deployer@vps-17410:/var/www/avto/releases/20160223182016$ bundle exec rails console
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                 # Default: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/bin/ruby
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to some application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
  -B, [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip .gitignore file
      [--skip-keeps]             # Skip source control .keep files
  -O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets]         # Skip Sprockets files
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                 # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]  # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                 # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]         # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--rc=RC]                  # Path to file containing extra configuration options for rails command
      [--no-rc]                  # Skip loading of extra configuration options from .railsrc file

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
```

Comment: Что-нибудь из `bin/rails` или `script/rails` там есть относительно этой папки? Потому что рельсы, [вроде как](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/app_loader.rb), ищут один из этих двух.

Comment: нет ничего, не помогает

Comment: Я не про запуск. Эти файлы существуют?

Comment: deployer@vps-17410:~$ which rails
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@avto/bin/rails

Comment: Где они должны быть? rvm по стандарту ставил

Comment: В проекте, `bin/rails` или `script/rails`. В 4.2 создаётся `bin/rails`, есть в означенной в вопросе папке такое?

Comment: это находится в bin/rails
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'

Comment: То есть, такой файл есть. Значит, такое поведение вызвано чем-то ещё, чего в вопросе нет. У меня нет идей.

Comment: Спасибо, решил проблему

Answer (score 1):

Была такая проблема после деплоя с помощью capistrano, решило проблему удаление папки `bin` из `linked_dirs`.

`linked_dirs` - это массив директорий, которые не должны обновляться при каждом деплое, например, изображения, кеш, скомпилированные файлы статики, логи. При добавлении названия директории в этот массив в папке shared будут создаваться дубли, на которые и будет ссылаться приложение.

В вашей конфигурации capistrano замените:

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('bin', 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system', 'public/assets', 'vendor/bundle')
```

на

```
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system', 'public/assets', 'vendor/bundle')
```

В качестве альтернативы попробуйте добавить файлы из вашей локальной папки `bin` в `shared/bin`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Причина проблемы в том, что если папка `bin` включена в массив `linked_dirs`, то current/bin ссылается на shared/bin, в которой отсутствуют файлы `bundle`, `rails`, `rake`. Из-за отсутствия файла `bin/rails` команда `rails c` не выполняется.

Comment: к сожалению не могу комментировать (только вот свои ответы), иначе бы задал вопрос, что у вопрошающего в папке shared/bin находится, он указал содержимое, но не уточнил, на сервере этот файл или в локальной копии проекта

Comment: Спасибо, попробую ваш вариант